# How to set a custom UIToolBar always in the front and top of the application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I've been stuck with this for a while now. Im trying to put a custom toolbar always in the front of my iPad application (in the front of other views), however im not sure how to tell the UIApplicationDelegate to establish it as the parent view.

I tried using a navigation controller but i need it stuck always in the top and i couldn't get rid of the transition animation when changing views.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can set the Zorder property of toolbar to 1

Comment: yourToolBar.layer.zPosition=1; i hope this will help you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set that custom toolbar in main window or add that toolbar programmatically as a subview in your window,
and after that in all your child view controller set view size,
For example if your toolbar has height of 50px that the X position of your all child view must be start with 50px.

This approach is works for me,
Hope it will help you also.