# iOS - Insert subview between the background and toolbar of another view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Pardon my ugly illustration below:

[image]

I have a view controller A that has a toolbar T at the bottom; toolbar is part of controller A, created by choosing "Opaque Toolbar" as "Bottom Bar" in the Attributes Inspector of view controller A. I'd like a banner B to slide up from the top of toolbar T, stay there for 2 seconds then disappear. Banner B is not within the view hierarchy of controller A. The issue right now is that the banner covers the toolbar during the sliding up process; I'd like the notification banner to emerge from the top of the toolbar, initially completely covered by the toolbar, instead of covering the toolbar.

Changing the layer index of the banner doesn't work, because the banner is not within the layer system of the view below it.

Here's my code snippet that adds the banner and animates it:

```
[containerView addSubview:innerView];

// Animate In
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
    [innerView setFrame:target];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    if (finished) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
        [innerView addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
    }
}];
```

Is there a way to insert the banner so that it appears above the background of controller A but below the toolbar of the controller?

Comment: Container view  contains your toolBar?

Comment: @ReinierMelian that's correct. toolBar was created in Attributes inspector -> Bottom Bar dropdown then chose Opaque toolbar, so it's part of the container view

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try :

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront : toolbarView]; //Top level
[self.view insertSubview:bannerView belowSubview: toolBarView]; //below your toolbar
```

Comment: toolBarView is not a separate view but part of container view, created in Attributes inspector -> Bottom Bar dropdown then chose Opaque toolbar. If there's a way to get the toolbar view from its view controller please let me know!

Comment: do you really need this Bottom Bar dropdown  ? Because it's easy to represent your mock-ups with a UIStackView from the storyboard and with constraints

Comment: well I think that @Anthony Roani Answer can help you, please let me know

Comment: @AnthonyRoani I need this bottom bar dropdown because I have 10+ view controllers all of the same format (a toolbar at the bottom), I don't want to attach a separate toolbar to every one of my controllers. (And logically speaking, the toolbar is an integral part of the view controller anyway)

Comment: Ok, hmm check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169757/how-to-set-a-custom-uitoolbar-always-in-the-front-and-top-of-the-application

Answer (score 0):

I assume your `containerView` is the view of a `UINavigationController`, as you cannot add a toolbar in the attributes inspector for `UIViewController`. I would suggest you just add the banner to `self.view`

```
[self.view addSubview:innerView];
```

If you feel like this will not work. You should probably subclass `UINavigationController` and add the subview of it.

```
[self.view insertSubview:bannerView belowSubview: self.toolbar]; //toolbar is a property of UINavigationController
```

I suppose it's possible to say something like:

```
[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:bannerView belowSubview: self.navigationController.toolBarView];
```

Generally you want view controllers to manager their own view hierarchy. So it is better to avoid the third options.

Comment: Hi @beyowulf, sorry for the late reply, just had a chance of trying this out. `insertSubview:belowSubview` did not work for me, because `bannerView` is not within the same view hierarchy as self.view and its toolbar. The result was that even though I specified `belowSubview`, banner still appeared over self.view and its toolbar. In fact I did a little experiment by using "insertSubview:atIndex"; when index < 1, banner appears below self.view and toolbar; when index >= 1, banner appears above both self.view and toolbar. There's no value that would put the banner in between self.view and toolbar

Comment: I gave three different possible solutions. You're not clear in which one your trying. You should try updating your question to be more specific about the structure of your application, maybe by adding screen shots of your storyboard or xib files. It will make it easier for others to help you.